# Spring AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests - Preventing database rollback after each Junit test

Tags: java, spring, dbunit

I have a test class that extends AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests.

I did not write this class, and need to make a small change. I'd like to see what would happen if i prevented the recreation of the test database (using DbUnit) after each test.

I have tried playing with the following lines:

```
@Override
protected void onSetUpBeforeTransaction() throws Exception {
    initialisingTables.create("Init");
}

@Override
protected void onTearDownAfterTransaction() throws Exception {
    deleteTables(true);
    deleteTables(false);
}
```

But nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have to annotate your test methods with

```
@Rollback(false)
```

or the test class with sometjing like this:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txMgr", defaultRollback=false)
```

See: [10.3.3. JDBC Testing Support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-support-jdbc)